# Realloc an array of pointers on a struct / Increment a new value to an array of pointers

Tags: c

I'd like to realloc my array of pointers or just a way of adding 1 more spot on my array:

```
void global (void)
{
    FILE * flot;
    Logement *log[100]; // I tried putting **log; instead to make it dynamic but it doesn't work.
    int nbLog;
    flot = fopen("Logements.txt","r");
    if(flot == NULL)
        { //error 
            }
    nbLog=chargeLogement(flot,log,100);
    fclose(flot);
    *log=addLogement(log,&nbLog,100);
    nbLog=deletfunc(log,nbLog);
}

int chargeLogement(FILE * fe, Logement **log,int max)
{
    Logement l;
    int i=0;
    l=lireLogement(fe);
    while(!feof(fe))
    {
        if(i==max)
        { //error array full 
            }

        log[i]=(Logement *)malloc(sizeof(Logement));

        if(log[i]==NULL)
            { //error malloc
            }
        *log[i]=l;
        i++;
        l=lireLogement(fe);
    }
    return i;
}

Logement *addLogement(Logement **log,int *nbLog,int max)
{
    Logement l;
    if(*nbLog+1 == max)
    {
        // error array full
    }
    l=infoLogement(l,log,*nbLog); // infoLogements get info for new Logement l, typed by the user.
    *log=(Logement *)realloc(*log, (*nbLog + 1) * sizeof (Logement));
    if(*log==NULL)
    {
    // realloc error
    }
    *log[*nbLog]=l;
    *nbLog +=1;
    return *log;
}

int deletfunc (Logement **log,int nbLog)
{
        char ref[6];
        int pos,i;

        printf("\tEnter Reference to be deleted: ");
        scanf("%s%*c",ref);

        pos=rechDichoLogement(ref,log,nbLog); //rechDichoLogement looks for a value (ref) in the array and returns its position (pos)
        if(pos==-1)
        {
        printf("\nLogement doesn't exist.\n");
        return -1;
        }
        free(log[pos]);
        for(i=pos;i<nbLog-1;i++)
            log[i]=log[i+1];
        return nbLog-1;
}
```

- global is the function that calles other functions, it first loads the data (chargelogement), then adds a new spot with data typed by the user(addLogement) and lastly deletes the value typed by the user (delfunction).
- chargeLogement loads data from a txt file using malloc and returns the logical size of the array.
- addLogement should increment a new value.
- deletefun deletes value from array using a search function that returns the positions.

This code is a mess, it somehow works but combining the adding a value with realloc and then trying to delete it doesn't work (says free(): invalid pointer, Abandon). I'm guessing addLogement doesn't return the correct array.

Comment: `free(log[pos]);` What is `pos`? Its definition is not shown anywhere in the code. And where is the `main` code? Please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: What do you think happens to your `Logement *log[100];` variable when the `global()` function returns?

Comment: What is `rechDichoLogement`? How are the functions called? Code is still incomplete. Please review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your `log` is an array of `Logement*`.

However here: `*log=(Logement *)realloc(*log, (*nbLog + 1) * sizeof (Logement));` you're trying to make the first element of that array point to a new array you're allocating. This inevitably leads to memory leak.

If you define your array on stack with a specific size, as you did, you cannot reallocate it later on. To make the array re-allocateable you'll need to allocate it on heap (I.e.: before you use `realloc` you have to have `malloc` somewhere).

You are also passing `log` around by value, but if you intend to change the value of `log` itself, not what it points to, that will not work.

Comment: So, to solve my problem I would need to `*log=(Logement *)malloc(*nbLog * sizeof(Logement));` before realloc then initialize a new array and reallocate it ? `Logement **aux ; 
*aux=(Logement *)realloc(*log, (*nbLog + 1) * sizeof (Logement)); 
*log=*aux; 
free(*aux); `
Thanks .

Comment: @Zipen not really... I suggest you read a bit more about heap allocations, malloc/realloc, and how to manage pointers. It's really not something I can put in my answer. Understanding these concepts is the key to using C as a language.